# Unexpected Maven dependency mediation behavior

Tags: java, maven

I am encountering a very strange maven dependency mediation behavior. I am using

```
$ mvn -version
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=128M; support was removed in 8.0
Apache Maven 3.3.3 (7994120775791599e205a5524ec3e0dfe41d4a06; 2015-04-22T04:57:37-07:00)
Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.3.3/libexec
Java version: 1.8.0_51, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
```

The dependency section of my `pom` is like this:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.company.app</groupId>
        <artifactId>foo</artifactId>
        <version>3.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.company.app</groupId>
        <artifactId>bar</artifactId>
        <version>3.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-cli</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-cli</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

When I run `mvn clean compile` it fails with this error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project my-module: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /Users/morpheus/my-project/my-module/src/main/java/com/company/app/Main.java:[23,32] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   method builder(java.lang.String)
[ERROR] location: class org.apache.commons.cli.Option
```

This error is happening because maven is using an older version of `commons-cli` (older than 1.3.1 which I have clearly asked it to use). I changed the order of dependencies to:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-cli</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-cli</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.company.app</groupId>
        <artifactId>foo</artifactId>
        <version>3.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.company.app</groupId>
        <artifactId>bar</artifactId>
        <version>3.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

and now the error went away! This is a blatant violation of maven's stated [dependency mediation rules](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html). Is this not a bug in maven?